# Delphi Indy HTTPS detect the newest file from a web server

Tags: http, delphi, https, indy

What is the correct approach in trying to detect the name of the newest file add into a web server? I'm trying to download a file using Indy HTTPS.The filename is dynamically generated so I first need to determine what is the name of the newest file that exists on the server.

I use the following code to download the file from the webserver:

```
function getIndyFile_from_https(const fileURL, FileName: String): boolean;
var http:TIdHttp;
    s:TFileStream;
    i:integer;
    FProgress: Integer;
    FBytesToTransfer: Int64;
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    IOHndl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    protocol_url,fullurl,url_fara_protocol,host:string;

begin
http:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
IOHndl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
http.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
  //Request.Accept:='text/html,*/*';
  //Request.AcceptEncoding:='utf-8';
http.HandleRedirects := True;
http.IOHandler := IOHndl;
http.ReadTimeout := 30000;
//http.OnWork := HTTPWork;
//http.OnWorkBegin := HTTPWorkBegin;
//http.OnWorkEnd := HTTPWorkEnd;

  try
    s:=TFileStream.Create(filename, fmcreate);
    try
      http.Get(fileUrl,s);
      result:=true;
    finally
      s.free;
    end;
  finally
    http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard HTTP command which retrieves a file list.

Some specific server installation may return file lists for given path / directory URLs, but then you need to parse the HTTP response programmatically.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

You need server-side logic to handle this issue.  In response to a given static URL that your client can request, the server needs to either:

1. keep track of the newest file and return that filename, if not the file itself.
2. provide a directory listing that describes all available files and their timestamps. You can then parse the listing and request the newest file.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my assumptions.